Broken syntax highlighting after reinstalling windows in VSCode
I have a problem after reinstalling windows (screenshot):

"@staticmethod" Should be completely blue.
Instead of "tray", "self" should be red, a more saturated red.
"QSystemTrayIcon()" should have been white.

I have no idea what happened, the theme is installed the same. Semantic Highlighting is turned off. I've dug all over google, all over the vscode settings, but nothing works.

Semantic Highlighting is what provides the colors for the different symbols, so keep that on. The Python and Pylance extensions are required for it to work, so make sure they're installed from the marketplace.

mattmess1221, All python extensions are installed

You can try these things and see if you can solve the problem.

Use the shortcut Ctrl+, to set editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled to true.
You can try to click Switch to Pre-Release Version to reinstall the Python extension.
You can find the backup file before installing the Windows system. Generally in settings.json documents. Replace the backed up files to the correct path.


When using semanticHighlighting, the whole code turns yellow, which is very annoying to the eye. Also, when semanticHighlighting is used italic font...

Hello, can you find your previous backup file and settings it.
